# How to get reports from a Routing Instance in Trimble Maps JavaScript Maps SDK?

Tags: javascript, sdk, report, trimble-maps

I would like to get mileage data using Trimble Maps Routing. The getReports() method in a Routing instance should provide this information. However, anytime i call this method i receive null. How can i get mile reports from either TrimbleMaps.Map or TrimbleMaps.Route instances?

documentation: https://developer.trimblemaps.com/maps-sdk/api/#route

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://maps-sdk.trimblemaps.com/v2/trimblemaps-2.1.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="height: 600px; width: 800px;"></div>

<script src="https://maps-sdk.trimblemaps.com/v2/trimblemaps-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>

  TrimbleMaps.APIKey = "17CA0885B03A6B4FADBDC3D1A51DC0BD";

  let map = new TrimbleMaps.Map({
    container: "map",
    center: new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(-80.1709, 25.7745),
    zoom: 10
  });

  map.on('load', () => {
    let myRoute = new TrimbleMaps.Route({
      routeId: 'myRoute',
      stops: [
        new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(-80.35564219999999, 25.7632547),
        new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(-80.20527899999999, 25.8180518)
      ],
      reportType: [TrimbleMaps.Common.ReportType.MILEAGE]
    });
    myRoute.addTo(map);
    console.log(myRoute.getReports()); // undefined
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the javascript API Trimble Maps.

myRoute.getReports() function has a listener do the following:

```
const myRoute = new TrimbleMaps.Route({
  routeId: "myRoute",
  stops: [
      new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(-74.566234, 40.49944),
      new TrimbleMaps.LngLat(-74.629749, 40.26118)
    ],
    reportType: [
      TrimbleMaps.Common.ReportType.MILEAGE,
      TrimbleMaps.Common.ReportType.DETAIL
    ]
  });


  // *** THIS IS THE LISTENER ****
  myRoute.on("report", function (reports) {
    console.log(reports);
  });
```

Reference: https://developer.trimblemaps.com/maps-sdk/guide/routing/

Answer (score 0):

Trimble MAPS does offer Routing Reports via the Maps Javascript platform as well as the Web Services API. The code sample you have referenced is functional but requires a Trimble MAPS API Key that includes Javascript functionality.

As for Web Services API Reporting, that documentation is located here:

REST: https://developer.trimblemaps.com/restful-apis/routing/route-reports/
SOAP: https://developer.trimblemaps.com/soap-apis/docs/reports/get-reports/

Here is an examples of a REST Mileage Report:
https://pcmiler.alk.com/apis/rest/v1.0/Service.svc/route/routeReports?stops=-87.959895,42.030182;-87.572483,41.673633&reports=Mileage&dataVersion=Current&authToken=INSERT API KEY

Comment: We're in the process of getting the JavaScript Maps added to our account but i was hoping i could test first through some type of sandbox key. I'll wait until we get an authorized key. Thank you.

Comment: We purchased the JavaScript Maps but we're still having the same issue. Everything on the map works but the reports are still coming back undefined. I believe we have PC Miler Web Services & now the Maps.

We're able to use the REST Mileage report which we do as a work around but getting the routing reports from the Map JavaScript would save us a lot of calls.